# I am sending an mail from mailgun using laravel 6.actually mails getting delivered but in spam not in inbox

Tags: laravel, mailgun

Why is this message in spam? It is similar to messages that were identified as spam in the past

Answer (score 0):

If your email id an company email id (`user@company.com`) then it will go to spam until user tells the server that this is not a spam.

Open that email which you received in spam, then you see a button which says `not a spam`. After clicking that button you will receive email in your inbox.

If you still face difficulties then read this  [mailgun 's article](https://help.mailgun.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011702394-Why-Do-My-Emails-Go-to-Spam-) or contact with mailgun support.